# Is there a better way to tidy this chuck of code? It is the Runge-Kutta 4th order with 4 ODEs

Tags: python, runge-kutta

```
def xpos(x,y,t):    #dx/dt = v_x 
    return vx 

def ypos(x,y,t):  #dy/dt = v_y 
    return vy 

def xvel(x,y,t):   #dv_x/dt = -GMx/r^3 
    return -G*M*x/((x)**2 + (y)**2)**1.5

def yvel(x,y,t):    # dv_y/dt = -GMy/r^3
    return -G*M*y/((x)**2 + (y)**2)**1.5 

xposk1 = h*xpos(x,y,t)
yposk1 = h*ypos(x,y,t)
xvelk1 = h*xvel(x,y,t)
yvelk1 = h*yvel(x,y,t)

xposk2 = h*xpos(x+(0.5*xposk1),y+(0.5*yposk1),t+(0.5*h))
yposk2 = h*ypos(x+(0.5*xposk1),y+(0.5*yposk1),t+(0.5*h))
xvelk2 = h*xvel(x+(0.5*xvelk1),y+(0.5*yvelk1),t+(0.5*h))
yvelk2 = h*xvel(x+(0.5*xvelk1),y+(0.5*yvelk1),t+(0.5*h))

xposk3 = h*xpos(x+(0.5*xposk2),y+(0.5*yposk2),t+(0.5*h))
yposk3 = h*ypos(x+(0.5*xposk2),y+(0.5*yposk2),t+(0.5*h))
xvelk3 = h*xvel(x+(0.5*xvelk2),y+(0.5*yvelk2),t+(0.5*h))
yvelk3 = h*yvel(x+(0.5*xvelk2),y+(0.5*yvelk2),t+(0.5*h))

xposk4 = h*xpos(x+xposk3,y+yposk3,t+h)
yposk4 = h*ypos(x+xposk3,y+yposk3,t+h)
xvelk4 = h*xvel(x+xvelk3,y+yvelk3,t+h)
yvelk4 = h*yvel(x+xvelk3,y+yvelk3,t+h)
```

Here I have 4 ODEs (Ordinary Differential Equations) that I want to solve using the Runge-Kutta 4th order method. The code I've included above should be able to do it but I was curious if there is a much simpler and shorter way of doing it. I have only included the relevant (RK4) part of the code.

Comment: Better than what way?

Comment: This code will not do it, since the position derivative is the velocity, which you do not pass as argument. You should indeed get an error in the second line of above code as `vx` is not defined.

Comment: You could be inspired by [Runge-Kutta code not converging with builtin method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35071393/3088138), or if you want to shorten the solution of the second order ODE another way, you can eliminate the xposk and yposk variables in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

As there are not enough planetary orbit simulations using RK4 (if you stay on this topic, quickly switch to an adaptive time stepping method that follows the speed variations along an elliptical orbit).

The acceleration vector of the position vector `x` can be computed compactly as

```
def acc(x):
   r3 = sum(x**2)**1.5;
   return -G*M*x/r3
```

where it is supposed that `x` is always a numpy array.

Following the reduction of RK4 in the second order ODE case [as computed here (and in many other places)](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/34330/6839) the RK4 step can be implemented as

```
def RK4step(x,v,h):
    dv1 = h*acc(x)
    dv2 = h*acc(x+0.5*h*v)
    dv3 = h*acc(x+0.5*h*(v+0.5*dv1))
    dv4 = h*acc(x+h*(v+0.5*dv2))
    return x+h*(v+(dv1+dv2+dv3)/6), v+(dv1+2*(dv2+dv3)+dv4)/6
```