# Rk4 Integrator of a nonlinear second order ODE in Python

Tags: python, ode, runge-kutta, orbital-mechanics

I'm in a project in my University and I have to implement the Runge-Kutta 4-order integrator using Python.
I know I can use for example Sympy, but the goal here is implement the method, the code is ready written in Fortran language, so basically I have a data base with the correct values of solutions and I have to get similar solutions in my code. However, we have some problems; I did the same several times using linear equations ( first and second order ), however this is a second order nonlinear equation from Newton universal law of gravitation.
The code has no error, my problem is what my code is doing wrong that I cannot get the right results.

Below I'll show some of the expected values and the ones i'm getting, after them I'll show the code.

I'd be really pleasured if someone could help me.

RIGHT RESULTS (expected results)

```
  r           t (days)

-12912.5186     .0000
-13135.2914     .0023
-13342.8424     .0046
-13534.9701     .0069
-13711.4971     .0093
-13872.2704     .0116
-14017.1611     .0139
-14146.0643     .0162
-14258.8997     .0185
-14355.6106     .0208
-14436.1641     .0231
-14500.5505     .0255
-14548.7833     .0278
-14580.8984     .0301
-14596.9536     .0324
-14597.0282     .0347
-14581.2222     .0370
-14549.6560     .0394
-14502.4692     .0417
-14439.8201     .0440
-14361.8851     .0463
-14268.8576     .0486
-14160.9475     .0509
-14038.3802     .0532
-13901.3958     .0556
-13750.2482     .0579
-13585.2046     .0602
-13406.5442     .0625
-13214.5576     .0648
-13009.5461     .0671
-12791.8207     .0694
-12561.7015     .0718
-12319.5167     .0741
-12065.6021     .0764
-11800.2999     .0787
-11523.9589     .0810
-11236.9327     .0833
-10939.5799     .0856
-10632.2630     .0880
-10315.3480     .0903
-9989.2038      .0926
-9654.2014      .0949
-9310.7139      .0972
-8959.1154      .0995
```

WRONG RESULTS (from the code below)

```
  r            t (seconds)

-12912.518615   0.000000
-10894.236220   3600.000000
-8051.384478    7200.000000
-2829.162198    10800.000000
39786.739120    14400.000000
39564.796772    18000.000000
39340.531265    21600.000000
39113.878351    25200.000000
38884.770893    28800.000000
38653.138691    32400.000000
38418.908276    36000.000000
38182.002705    39600.000000
37942.341331    43200.000000
37699.839549    46800.000000
37454.408529    50400.000000
37205.954917    54000.000000
36954.380518    57600.000000
36699.581939    61200.000000
36441.450207    64800.000000
36179.870344    68400.000000
35914.720909    72000.000000
35645.873482    75600.000000
35373.192107    79200.000000
35096.532668    82800.000000
34815.742202    86400.000000
```

Obs.: Before I show the code the first part of it before the implementation is completely right, the problem is in the integrator function, I'm just trying to see the results, that's why the velocity is not being computed since if my r vector is right, v will be as well.
The equation is :
**r''**(vector) = -(GM/r³)***r**(vector)

### CODE

```
import numpy as np

# alternative to not typing all the time

TINTE = 5           #days 
a = 26551.0         #kilometers
e = 0.1             
i = 55              #degrees
OM = 102            #degrees
w = 32              #degrees
f = 12              #degrees

# Mass of central body

Mc = 5.97240e+24     #kg (Earth = 7.97240D+24    Sol = 1.98850D+30)
M2 = 5.97240e+24     #kg (Earth = 7.97240D+24    Sol = 1.98850D+30)
M3 = 7.34600e+22     #kg Mass of the Moon
G = 6.67408e-20      #Value prepared for km
#Mi = Mc/(M2+M3)      #G*Mc - alternatively
#PI = math.acos(-1.0) 
TN = 27.321660       #Time converter

# Dados do Sistema

tempo = list()
xc = list()
yc = list()
zc = list()

#Transformation of orbital elements in position and velocity in the ECI coordinate system

P = a*(1-e**2)
R = P/(1+e*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(f))))

X = list()
X.append(R*((np.cos(np.deg2rad(OM)))*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(w+f))) - (np.sin(np.deg2rad(OM)))*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(i)))*(np.sin(np.deg2rad(w+f)))))
X.append(R*((np.sin(np.deg2rad(OM)))*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(w+f))) + (np.cos(np.deg2rad(OM)))*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(i)))*(np.sin(np.deg2rad(w+f)))))
X.append(R*(np.sin(np.deg2rad(i)))*(np.sin(np.deg2rad(w+f))))

V = list()
V.append((-(Mi/P)**0.5)*((np.cos(np.deg2rad(OM)))*((np.sin(np.deg2rad(w+f)))+e*(np.sin(np.deg2rad(w)))) + (np.sin(np.deg2rad(OM)))*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(i)))*((np.cos(np.deg2rad(w+f))) + e*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(w))))))
V.append((-(Mi/P)**0.5)*((np.sin(np.deg2rad(OM)))*((np.sin(np.deg2rad(w+f)))+e*(np.sin(np.deg2rad(w)))) - (np.cos(np.deg2rad(OM)))*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(i)))*((np.cos(np.deg2rad(w+f))) + e*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(w))))))
V.append(((Mi/P)**0.5)*((np.sin(np.deg2rad(i)))*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(w+f)))+e*(np.cos(np.deg2rad(w)))))

Vp = (V[0]**2 + V[1]**2 + V[2]**2)**0.5

xc.append(X[0])
yc.append(X[1])
zc.append(X[2])

Vx = V[0]
Vy = V[1]
Vz = V[2]

def RUNGE_KUTAH_4(X,V):
    
    #variables
    RT = 6370                  #km
    G = 6.67408e-20            #Value prepared for km
    p = X
    ç = V
    R = ( p[0]**2 + p[1]**2 + p[2]**2 )**0.5
    R3 = R*R*R
    Ve = Vp
        
    # initial state
    tempo.append(0)
    t = 0
    r1 = p[0]
    r2 = p[1]
    r3 = p[2]
    u1 = ç[0]
    u2 = ç[1]
    u3 = ç[2]
    
    #step
    delta_t = 3600
    
    def rk4(r,u,R3):
        m1 = u
        k1 = -((G*Mc)/(R3))*r
        m2 = u + 0.5*delta_t*k1
        t_2 = t + 0.5*delta_t
        r_2 = r + 0.5*delta_t*m1
        u_2 = m2
        k2 = -((G*Mc)/(R3))*r
        m3 = u + 0.5*delta_t*k2
        t_3 = t + 0.5*delta_t
        r_3 = r + 0.5*delta_t*m2
        u_3 = m3
        k3 = -((G*Mc)/(R3))*r
        m4 = u + 0.5*delta_t*k3
        t_4 = t + delta_t
        r_4 = r + delta_t*m3
        u_4 = m4
        k4 = -((G*Mc)/(R3))*r
        
        r = r + (delta_t/6)*(m1+2*(m2+m3)+m4)
        u = u + (delta_t/6)*(k1+2*(k2+k3)+k4)
        
        return [r,u]
        

    # step by step solution 
    lim = 86400*TINTE
    while t < lim:
        r1 = rk4(r1,u1,R3)[0]
        r2 = rk4(r2,u2,R3)[0]
        r3 = rk4(r3,u3,R3)[0]
        
        R = (r1**2 + r2**2 + r3**2)**0.5
        R3 = R*R*R
        t += delta_t
        
        tempo.append(t)
        xc.append(r1)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RUNGE_KUTAH_4(X,V)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inventor of the Runge-Kutta methods was really named Martin Wilhelm Kutta. (Runge 1895 did something strange, Heun 1900 made it less strange, Kutta 1901 made it fully flexible and systematic.)

You have a severe conceptual error in your implementation.

- You need to treat a coupled system as a coupled system, you can not de-couple the integration of the components. At best you will get a first order integrator this way.
- This is especially visible and egregious in your use of `R3`. This value needs to be re-computed for every stage. If the derivatives vector depends on a function of the state, then this value can not be constant.

See [Cannot get RK4 to solve for position of orbiting body in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645649/cannot-get-rk4-to-solve-for-position-of-orbiting-body) and [Is there a better way to tidy this chuck of code? It is the Runge-Kutta 4th order with 4 ODEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405185/is-there-a-better-way-to-tidy-this-chuck-of-code) for working code examples.

Comment: Ok, I've taken a look in all of these topics you suggested me, so let me see if I got it right?  First, unlike other cases my acceleration is receiving an update of the velocity and the position of the velocity, right?

Comment: My mistake is because I de-coupled the integration of the components which not allows me to treat the system as a coupled one. 
So basically I'll have to treat all the components inside my 'rk4' function which it'll make me get triple of the declarations, that amount for each component (x,y,z) and solve it all together?

First place, thanks for the feedback; second place, may you tell me if I got right which ones were my mistakes and in negative case, what else I have to consider?

Comment: It appears that you understood correctly. In each RK4 stage you need to recompute R3, and for that you need the correctly updated values of (x,y,z). I strongly recommend to use vector operations so that you do not need to duplicate nearly identical instructions. This only leads to errors-by-typo, copy-paste errors.