# How to fix incorrect energy conservation problem in mass-spring-system simulation using RK4 method

Tags: simulation, runge-kutta

I am making a simulation where you create different balls of certain mass, connected by springs which you can define (in the program below all springs have natural length L and spring constant k). How I do it is **I created a function accel(b,BALLS), (note b is the specific ball and BALLS are all of the ball objects *in various stages of update*) which gets me acceleration on this one ball from calculating all the forces acting on it (tensions from ball the springs connected to it and gravity)** and I would think this function is definitely correct and problems lie elsewhere in the while loop. I then use the RK4 method described on this website: http://spiff.rit.edu/richmond/nbody/OrbitRungeKutta4.pdf in the while loop to update velocity and position of each ball. To test my understanding of the method I first made a simulation where only two balls and one spring is involved on Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4ag5gkerag
I allowed for energy display and saw that indeed RK4 is much better than Euler method. Now I  made it in python in the hope that it should work with arbitrary config of balls and springs, but energy isn't even conserved when I have two balls and one spring! I couldn't see what I did differently, at least when two balls on involved. And when I introduce a third ball and a second spring to the system, energy increases by the hundreds every second. This is my first time coding a simulation with RK4, and I expect you guys can find mistakes in it. I have an idea that maybe the problem is caused by because there are multiple bodies and difficulties arises when I update their kas or kvs at the same time but then again I can't spot any difference between what this code is doing when simulating two balls and my method used in the Desmos file. Here is my code in python:

```
    import pygame
    import sys
    import math
    import numpy as np
    
    
    pygame.init()
    width = 1200
    height = 900
    SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
    TIME = pygame.time.Clock()
    
    dampwall = 1
    dt = 0.003
    g = 20
    k=10
    L=200
    
    
    def dist(a, b):
        return math.sqrt((a[0] - b[0])*(a[0] - b[0]) + (a[1] - b[1])*(a[1] - b[1]))
    
    
    def mag(a):
        return dist(a, [0, 0])
    
    def dp(a, b):
        return a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]
    
    
    def norm(a):
        return list(np.array(a)/mag(a))
    
    
    def reflect(a, b):
        return norm([2*a[1]*b[0]*b[1]+a[0]*(b[0]**2 - b[1]**2), 2*a[0]*b[0]*b[1]+a[1]*(-b[0]**2 + b[1]**2)])
    
    
    
    
    class ball:
        def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, mass,spr,index,ka,kv):
            self.r = [x, y]
            self.v = [vx, vy]
    
            self.radius = 5
            self.mass = mass
            self.spr=spr
            self.index = index
            self.ka=ka
            self.kv=kv
            
        def detectbounce(self,width,height):
            if self.r[0] + self.radius > width/2 and self.r[0]+self.v[0] > self.r[0] or  self.r[0] - self.radius < -width/2 and self.r[0]+self.v[0] < self.r[0] or self.r[1] + self.radius > height/2 and self.r[1]+self.v[1] > self.r[1] or self.r[1] - self.radius < -height/2 and self.r[1]+self.v[1] < self.r[1]:
                return True
            
    
        def bounce_walls(self, width, height):
            
            
            if self.r[0] + self.radius > width/2 and self.r[0]+self.v[0] > self.r[0]:
                self.v[0] *= -dampwall
    
            if self.r[0] - self.radius < -width/2 and self.r[0]+self.v[0] < self.r[0]:
                self.v[0] *= -dampwall
    
            if self.r[1] + self.radius > height/2 and self.r[1]+self.v[1] > self.r[1]:
                self.v[1] *= -dampwall
    
            if self.r[1] - self.radius < -height/2 and self.r[1]+self.v[1] < self.r[1]:
                self.v[1] *= -dampwall
        
        
    
        def update_r(self,v, h):
    
            self.r[0] += v[0] * h 
            self.r[1] += v[1] * h
        
        def un_update_r(self,v, h):
    
            self.r[0] += -v[0] * h 
            self.r[1] += -v[1] * h
    
        
        def KE(self):
            return 0.5 * self.mass * mag(self.v)**2
    
        def GPE(self):
            return self.mass * g * (-self.r[1] + height)
        
    
        def draw(self, screen, width, height):
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (self.r[0] +
                               width / 2, self.r[1] + height / 2), self.radius)
            
    
    
    
    #(self, x, y, vx, vy, mass,spr,index,ka,kv):
    # balls = [ball(1, 19, 0, 0,5,[1],0,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]), ball(250, 20, 0,0,1,[0],1,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0])]   
    # springs = [[0, 1]]
    
    balls = [ball(1, 19, 0, 0,5,[1,3],0,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]), ball(250, 20, 0,0,2,[0,2,3],1,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]),ball(450, 0, 0,0,2,[1,3],1,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]),ball(250, -60, 0,0,2,[0,1,2],1,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0])]   
    springs = [[0, 1],[1,2],[0,3],[1,3],[2,3]]
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    def accel(b,BALLS):
    
        A=[0,g]
        for i in range(0,len(b.spr)):
            ball1=b
            ball2=BALLS[b.spr[i]]
            r1 = norm(list(np.array(ball2.r) - np.array(ball1.r)))
            lnow = dist(ball1.r, ball2.r)
            force = k * (lnow - L)
            A[0]+=force/ball1.mass*r1[0]
            A[1]+=force/ball1.mass*r1[1]
            
        return A
            
    initE=0
    while True:
        TIME.tick(200)
        SCREEN.fill((0, 0, 0))
    
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
    
        #compute k1a and k1v for all balls
        for ball in balls:
    
                ball.ka[0]=accel(ball,balls)
                ball.kv[0]=ball.v
                
        #create newb1 based on 'updated' position of all balls with their own k1v
        newb=[]
        for ball in balls:
                ball.update_r(ball.kv[0], dt/2)
                newb.append(ball)
                ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[0], dt/2)
                
        #compute k2a and k2v for all balls based on newb1
        for ball in balls:
                ball.update_r(ball.kv[0], dt/2)
                ball.ka[1]=accel(ball,newb)
                ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[0], dt/2)
                
                ball.kv[1]=[ball.v[0]+0.5*dt*ball.ka[0][0],ball.v[1]+0.5*dt*ball.ka[0][1]]
    
        #create newb2 based on 'updated' position of all balls with their own k2v       
        newb=[]
        for ball in balls:
     
                ball.update_r(ball.kv[1], dt/2)
                newb.append(ball)
                ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[1], dt/2)
                
        #compute k3a and k3v for all balls
        for ball in balls:
            
                ball.update_r(ball.kv[1], dt/2)
                ball.ka[2]=accel(ball,newb)
                ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[1], dt/2)
                
                ball.kv[2]=[ball.v[0]+0.5*dt*ball.ka[1][0],ball.v[1]+0.5*dt*ball.ka[1][1]]
        
        newb=[]
        for ball in balls:
    
                ball.update_r(ball.kv[2], dt)
                newb.append(ball)
                ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[2], dt)
        
        #compute k4a and k4v for all balls
        for ball in balls:
                ball.update_r(ball.kv[2], dt)
                ball.ka[3]=accel(ball,newb)
                ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[2], dt)
                
                ball.kv[3]=[ball.v[0]+dt*ball.ka[2][0],ball.v[1]+dt*ball.ka[2][1]]
                
        #final stage of update
        for ball in balls:
            if ball.detectbounce(width,height)==True:
                ball.bounce_walls(width, height)
            else:
                ball.v=[ball.v[0]+dt*(ball.ka[0][0]+2*ball.ka[1][0]+2*ball.ka[2][0]+ball.ka[3][0])/6, ball.v[1]+dt*(ball.ka[0][1]+2*ball.ka[1][1]+2*ball.ka[2][1]+ball.ka[3][1])/6]
                ball.r=[ball.r[0]+dt*(ball.kv[0][0]+2*ball.kv[1][0]+2*ball.kv[2][0]+ball.kv[3][0])/6, ball.r[1]+dt*(ball.kv[0][1]+2*ball.kv[1][1]+2*ball.kv[2][1]+ball.kv[3][1])/6]
            
        for ball in balls:      
            ball.draw(SCREEN, width, height)
            for i in range(0,len(ball.spr)):
                ball1=ball
                ball2=balls[ball.spr[i]]
                pygame.draw.line(SCREEN, (0, 0, 155), (
                    ball1.r[0]+width/2, ball1.r[1]+height/2), (ball2.r[0]+width/2, ball2.r[1]+height/2))
        
        #check for energy        
                
        KE = 0
        EPE = 0
        GPE = 0
        for i in range(0, len(springs)):
    
            EPE += 1/2 * k * \
                (L - dist(balls[springs[i][0]].r,
                 balls[springs[i][1]].r))**2
    
        for i in range(0, len(balls)):
            KE += balls[i].KE()
            GPE += balls[i].GPE()
    
    
        if initE == 0:
                initE += KE+EPE+GPE
    
    
        text = font.render('init Energy: ' + str(round(initE,1))+' '+'KE: ' + str(round(KE, 1)) + ' '+'EPE: ' + str(round(EPE, 1))+' ' + 'GPE: ' + str(round(GPE, 1)) + ' ' + 'Total: ' + str(round(KE+EPE+GPE, 1)) + ' ' + 'Diff: ' + str(round((KE+EPE+GPE-initE), 1)),
                               True, (255, 255, 255))
    
        textRect = text.get_rect()
        textRect.center = (370, 70)
        SCREEN.blit(text, textRect)
                
    
        pygame.display.flip()
```

This is the edited, corrected by Lutz Lehmann and with some extra improvements:

```
import pygame
import sys
import math
import numpy as np


pygame.init()
width = 1200
height = 900
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
TIME = pygame.time.Clock()

dampwall = 1
dt = 0.003
g = 5
k = 10
L = 200

digits = 6


def dist(a, b):
    return math.sqrt((a[0] - b[0])*(a[0] - b[0]) + (a[1] - b[1])*(a[1] - b[1]))


def mag(a):
    return dist(a, [0, 0])


def dp(a, b):
    return a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]


def norm(a):
    return list(np.array(a)/mag(a))


def reflect(a, b):
    return norm([2*a[1]*b[0]*b[1]+a[0]*(b[0]**2 - b[1]**2), 2*a[0]*b[0]*b[1]+a[1]*(-b[0]**2 + b[1]**2)])


class Ball:
    def __init__(self, x, y, vx, vy, mass, spr, index, ka, kv):
        self.r = [x, y]
        self.v = [vx, vy]

        self.radius = 5
        self.mass = mass
        self.spr = spr
        self.index = index
        self.ka = ka
        self.kv = kv

    def copy(self):
        return Ball(self.r[0], self.r[1], self.v[0], self.v[1], self.mass, self.spr, self.index, self.ka, self.kv)

    def detectbounce(self, width, height):
        if self.r[0] + self.radius > width/2 and self.r[0]+self.v[0] > self.r[0] or self.r[0] - self.radius < -width/2 and self.r[0]+self.v[0] < self.r[0] or self.r[1] + self.radius > height/2 and self.r[1]+self.v[1] > self.r[1] or self.r[1] - self.radius < -height/2 and self.r[1]+self.v[1] < self.r[1]:
            return True

    def bounce_walls(self, width, height):

        if self.r[0] + self.radius > width/2 and self.r[0]+self.v[0] > self.r[0]:
            self.v[0] *= -dampwall

        if self.r[0] - self.radius < -width/2 and self.r[0]+self.v[0] < self.r[0]:
            self.v[0] *= -dampwall

        if self.r[1] + self.radius > height/2 and self.r[1]+self.v[1] > self.r[1]:
            self.v[1] *= -dampwall

        if self.r[1] - self.radius < -height/2 and self.r[1]+self.v[1] < self.r[1]:
            self.v[1] *= -dampwall

    def update_r(self, v, h):

        self.r[0] += v[0] * h
        self.r[1] += v[1] * h

    def un_update_r(self, v, h):

        self.r[0] += -v[0] * h
        self.r[1] += -v[1] * h

    def KE(self):
        return 0.5 * self.mass * mag(self.v)**2

    def GPE(self):
        return self.mass * g * (-self.r[1] + height)

    def draw(self, screen, width, height):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (0, 0, 255), (self.r[0] +
                           width / 2, self.r[1] + height / 2), self.radius)


# (self, x, y, vx, vy, mass,spr,index,ka,kv):


# balls = [Ball(1, 19, 0, 0, 1, [1], 0, [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]),
#          Ball(250, 20, 0, 0, 1, [0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0])]
# springs = [[0, 1]]

balls = [Ball(1, 19, 0, 0,5,[1,3],0,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]), Ball(250, 20, 0,0,2,[0,2,3],1,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]),Ball(450, 0, 0,0,2,[1,3],1,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]),Ball(250, -60, 0,0,2,[0,1,2],1,[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0])]

# n=5
# resprings=[]

# for i in range(0,n):
#     for j in range(0,n):
#         if i==0 and j==0:
#             resprings.append([1,2,n,n+1,2*n])
#         if i==n and j==0:
#             resprings.apend([n*(n-1)+1,n*(n-1)+2,n*(n-2),n*(n-3),n*(n-2)+1])
#         if j==0 and i!=0 or i!=n:
#             resprings.append([(i-1)*n+1,(i-1)*n+2,(i-2)*n,(i-2)*n+1,(i)*n,(i)*n+1])
        
            

def getsprings(B):
    S=[]
    for i in range(0,len(B)):
        theball=B[i]
        for j in range(len(theball.spr)):
            spring=sorted([i,theball.spr[j]])
            if spring not in S:
                S.append(spring)

    return S
            
    
springs = getsprings(balls)    
        
    





def accel(b, BALLS):

    A = [0, g]
    for i in range(0, len(b.spr)):
        ball1 = b
        ball2 = BALLS[b.spr[i]]
        r1 = norm(list(np.array(ball2.r) - np.array(ball1.r)))
        lnow = dist(ball1.r, ball2.r)
        force = k * (lnow - L)
        A[0] += force/ball1.mass*r1[0]
        A[1] += force/ball1.mass*r1[1]

    return A


initE = 0
while True:
    TIME.tick(200)
    SCREEN.fill((0, 0, 0))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    for ball in balls:
        ball.bounce_walls(width, height)

    # compute k1a and k1v for all balls
    for ball in balls:

        ball.ka[0] = accel(ball, balls)
        ball.kv[0] = ball.v

    # create newb1 based on 'updated' position of all balls with their own k1v
    newb = []
    for ball in balls:
        ball.update_r(ball.kv[0], dt/2)
        newb.append(ball.copy())
        ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[0], dt/2)

    # compute k2a and k2v for all balls based on newb1
    for ball in balls:
        ball.update_r(ball.kv[0], dt/2)
        ball.ka[1] = accel(ball, newb)
        ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[0], dt/2)

        ball.kv[1] = [ball.v[0]+0.5*dt*ball.ka[0]
                      [0], ball.v[1]+0.5*dt*ball.ka[0][1]]

    # create newb2 based on 'updated' position of all balls with their own k2v
    newb = []
    for ball in balls:

        ball.update_r(ball.kv[1], dt/2)
        newb.append(ball.copy())
        ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[1], dt/2)

    # compute k3a and k3v for all balls
    for ball in balls:

        ball.update_r(ball.kv[1], dt/2)
        ball.ka[2] = accel(ball, newb)
        ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[1], dt/2)

        ball.kv[2] = [ball.v[0]+0.5*dt*ball.ka[1]
                      [0], ball.v[1]+0.5*dt*ball.ka[1][1]]

    newb = []
    for ball in balls:

        ball.update_r(ball.kv[2], dt)
        newb.append(ball.copy())
        ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[2], dt)

    # compute k4a and k4v for all balls
    for ball in balls:
        ball.update_r(ball.kv[2], dt)
        ball.ka[3] = accel(ball, newb)
        ball.un_update_r(ball.kv[2], dt)

        ball.kv[3] = [ball.v[0]+dt*ball.ka[2][0], ball.v[1]+dt*ball.ka[2][1]]

    # final stage of update
    for ball in balls:
        ball.v = [ball.v[0]+dt*(ball.ka[0][0]+2*ball.ka[1][0]+2*ball.ka[2][0]+ball.ka[3][0])/6,
                  ball.v[1]+dt*(ball.ka[0][1]+2*ball.ka[1][1]+2*ball.ka[2][1]+ball.ka[3][1])/6]
        ball.r = [ball.r[0]+dt*(ball.kv[0][0]+2*ball.kv[1][0]+2*ball.kv[2][0]+ball.kv[3][0])/6,
                  ball.r[1]+dt*(ball.kv[0][1]+2*ball.kv[1][1]+2*ball.kv[2][1]+ball.kv[3][1])/6]

    for ball in balls:
        ball.draw(SCREEN, width, height)
        for i in range(0, len(ball.spr)):
            ball1 = ball
            ball2 = balls[ball.spr[i]]
            pygame.draw.line(SCREEN, (0, 0, 155), (
                ball1.r[0]+width/2, ball1.r[1]+height/2), (ball2.r[0]+width/2, ball2.r[1]+height/2))

    # check for energy

    KE = 0
    EPE = 0
    GPE = 0
    for i in range(0, len(springs)):

        EPE += 1/2 * k * \
            (L - dist(balls[springs[i][0]].r,
             balls[springs[i][1]].r))**2

    for i in range(0, len(balls)):
        KE += balls[i].KE()
        GPE += balls[i].GPE()

    if initE == 0:
        initE += KE+EPE+GPE
    
    
    text1 = font.render(f"initial energy: {str(round(initE, digits))}", True, (255, 255, 255))
    text2 = font.render(f"kinetic energy: {str(round(KE, digits))}", True, (255, 255, 255))
    text3 = font.render(f"elastic potential energy: {str(round(EPE, digits))}", True, (255, 255, 255))
    text4 = font.render(f"gravitational energy: {str(round(GPE, digits))}", True, (255, 255, 255))
    text5 = font.render(f"total energy: {str(round(KE + EPE + GPE, digits))}", True, (255, 255, 255))
    text6 = font.render(f"change in energy: {str(round(KE + EPE + GPE - initE, digits))}", True, (255, 255, 255))

    SCREEN.blit(text1, (10, 10))
    SCREEN.blit(text2, (10, 60))
    SCREEN.blit(text3, (10, 110))
    SCREEN.blit(text4, (10, 160))
    SCREEN.blit(text5, (10, 210))
    SCREEN.blit(text6, (10, 260))
    

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: You have too many moving pieces, it is easy to make a strange error there. During the RK4 step, use only one newb array. Keep the ball array constant in its positions and velocities. In each stage, make newb a proper copy of ball, not a second array to the same instance references. Update newb according to the stage formula. Compute forces in newb. Copy the relevant stage data back to ball. /// You can get away with only using the ka array, see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405185/is-there-a-better-way and links there to the derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate error seems to be this

```
    for ball in balls:
            ...
            newb1.append(ball)
            ...
```

as `ball` is just a reference to the `class ball` instance, thus `newb1` is a list of references to the objects in `balls`, it makes no difference if you manipulate the one or the other, it is always the same data records that get changed.

You need to apply a copy mechanism, as you have lists of lists, you need a deep copy, or a dedicated copy member method, else you just copy the array references in the `ball` instances, so you get different instances, but pointing to the same arrays.

It is probably not an error but still a bad idea to have the class name also as variable name in the same scope.

Comment: I edited the code and newb is not a copy of the balls list now, but doesn't seem to better the situation

Comment: I got what you mean. Thank you very much. The code works now. In fact, difference in energy is 0 up to 6 decimal places, which is much better than I thought it would! I am looking forward to do more elaborate things with this program like cloth simulation. I have now pasted the correct as well as the original incorrect code in my question. Thank you again!